# How do I find the intersection of two opposing involutes?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, plane-curves, transcendental-equations

I have two involutes of a circle. They are drawn from the same base circle, but one is offset from the other and faces the opposite direction (see plot below).

The parametric equations for the first involute are:

$$x = r_b (\cos(θ) + θ \sin(θ))$$
$$y = r_b (\sin(θ) - θ \cos(θ))$$

The parametric equations for the second involute are:

$$x = r_b (\cos(c-θ) - θ \sin(c-θ))$$
$$y = r_b (\sin(c-θ) + θ \cos(c-θ))$$

Where $r_b$ is the radius of the base circle, $c$ is a positive constant, and $θ \ge 0$ .

The angle their intersection point makes with the origin and $x$-axis is $c/2$ radians, but I can't find an expression that will give me either 1) the radius of the intersection point to complete the set of polar coordinates, or 2) the $(x,y)$ Cartesian coordinates.

I can't just set the parametric expressions equal to each other and solve this algebraically, because $θ\sin(θ)$ and $θ\cos(θ)$ are transcendental expressions and have no inverse.

I've tried putting in ranges of values for $c$, solving for the intersection numerically, and plotting the results, but the resulting points don't seem to line up with any of the functions - or combinations of functions - with which I am familiar.

The expression $θ_R = \sqrt{R² - r_b²} \div r_b$ gives the value of theta where the involute intersects a circle of radius $R$ (concentric with the base circle), from which I can get the coordinates of that intersection point, but that doesn't help when I don't have a value for the radius.

### Plots

Involutes and base circle:

[image: Plot of two involutes and their base circle.]

Locus of the point $x = c, y = \text{[radius of intersection]}$ with $r_b = 1$:

[image: Plot of locus of the intersection as c varies from zero to five]

Same plot zoomed in to show detail with $c$ close to zero:

[image: Plot of locus of intersection as c varies from zero to zero point one six]

Comment: I don't know why you expect to find an "algebraic" solution. 99.99% surely you will have to settle for a numerical solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve the system

$$\begin{cases}\cos(\theta) + \theta\sin(\theta)=\cos(c-\phi) + \phi\sin(c-\phi),
\\\sin(\theta)- \theta\cos(\theta)=\sin(c-\phi) - \phi\cos(c-\phi).\end{cases}$$

By squaring and adding the two equations,

$$1+\theta^2=1+\phi^2$$ and $\phi=\pm\theta$.

Then

$$1=\cos(\theta)(\cos(c-\phi) + \phi\sin(c-\phi))+\sin(\theta)(\sin(c-\phi) - \phi\cos(c-\phi))
\\=\cos(\phi-c-\theta)+\phi\sin(\phi-c-\theta).$$

If $\theta=\phi$,

$$\theta=\phi=\frac{\cos(c)-1}{\sin(c)}.$$

If $\theta=-\phi$, the equation is transcendental and must be solved numerically.

$$1=\cos(2\phi-c)+\phi\sin(2\phi-c).$$

Using

$$1=\sqrt{1+\phi^2}\cos\left(2\phi-c-\arctan\phi\right),$$

you can express $c$ as a function of $\phi$.

Comment: Could you describe each step a bit more? I don't think I'm quite following you here. For example, why do you introduce a second paramater variable? The roll angle for both involutes must be the same at any intersection because they share the same base circle, so I'm not sure why you split them up.

Comment: @Lawton: two curves have a priori different parameters. But here computation revealed that $\theta=\pm\phi$, as you expected (plus another solution).

Comment: The θ = −ϕ equation matches my math when restricted to $c > 0$ and $\frac c2 < ϕ < \frac c2 + \frac \pi2$. Is there any way to manipulate it or the equation that follows it to get $ϕ$ as a function of $c$?

Comment: I just noticed a sign error where you write the system of equations, but since you square everything I think it goes away in the later steps.